# Is there a function to count the number of rows for a given condition?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way where I could get this desired output using mutate()? The idea is to count the number of consecutive values above 5.5 in each sequence of the Speed column. Ideally, it would also be best to get a function that could determine a "Start" and "End." E.g. in this example it would START at 5.5 and END at 5.9.

```
Speed <- c(0.1, 0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 2.8, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 0.1, 0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 2.8, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9) 
Number <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

df <- data.frame(Speed, Number)
df

     Speed Number
    1    0.1      0
    2    0.2      0
    3    1.2      0
    4    1.5      0
    5    2.8      0
    6    5.5      1
    7    5.6      2
    8    5.7      3
    9    5.8      4
    10   5.9      5
    11   0.1      0
    12   0.2      0
    13   1.2      0
    14   1.5      0
    15   2.8      0
    16   5.5      1
    17   5.6      2
    18   5.7      3
    19   5.8      4
    20   5.9      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a group to demarcate your different speeds, your example is basically a repetition of the same thing, but let's say:

```
df %>% 
mutate(group=cumsum(Speed==0.1)) %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(Number=cumsum(Speed>5))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   Speed Number group
   <dbl>  <int> <int>
 1   0.1      0     1
 2   0.2      0     1
 3   1.2      0     1
 4   1.5      0     1
 5   2.8      0     1
 6   5.5      1     1
 7   5.6      2     1
 8   5.7      3     1
 9   5.8      4     1
10   5.9      5     1
11   0.1      0     2
12   0.2      0     2
13   1.2      0     2
14   1.5      0     2
15   2.8      0     2
16   5.5      1     2
17   5.6      2     2
18   5.7      3     2
19   5.8      4     2
20   5.9      5     2
```

And to get min and max:

```
df %>% 
mutate(group=cumsum(Speed==0.1)) %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(Number=cumsum(Speed>5)) %>% 
filter(Number>0) %>% 
summarise(start=min(Speed),end=max(Speed))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group start   end
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   5.5   5.9
2     2   5.5   5.9
```